# Infinte Loop in React while using navigator.geolocation.watchPosition

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, geolocation

So I am trying to get the position of the user and store it in a `React.State`. I have a settings page where the user can set `settings.positionAllowed` to either `true` or `false` by pressing a button, false is the default value. Until pressing the button, everything works fine. But as soon as the user sets the setting to true and goes back to home page, an endless loop is created and the app crashes after some time. I first thought that the reason for this is that an instance of `navigator.geolovation.watchPosition` is created on every re-rendering of the component. But also the effect hook did not solve the problem.

Here is my code:

```
navigator.geolocation ? let posObj = {positionAllowed: false} : let posObj = {positionAllowed: true};

const [settings, setSettings] = useState(posObj);
useEffect(() => {
    if(settings.positionAllowed&&navigator.geolocation){
        let geolocation = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((rawPosition)=>{
            let positionData = {
                positionAvailable: true,
                    data: rawPosition
                }
                if(positionData!=position){
                    setPosition(positionData);
                }
            },(err)=>{
                console.log(err);
            },{
                enableHighAccuracy: true,
                maximumAge: 10000
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass [] as the second parameter of `useEffect`. Then, it will work like `componentDidMount()` in the class component. Unless, it will be called every time the state's updated, and will occur infinite loops.

```
navigator.geolocation ? let posObj = {positionAllowed: false} : let posObj = {positionAllowed: true};

const [settings, setSettings] = useState(posObj);
useEffect(() => {
    if(settings.positionAllowed&&navigator.geolocation){
        let geolocation = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((rawPosition)=>{
            let positionData = {
                positionAvailable: true,
                    data: rawPosition
                }
                if(positionData!=position){
                    setPosition(positionData);
                }
            },(err)=>{
                console.log(err);
            },{
                enableHighAccuracy: true,
                maximumAge: 10000
            });
        }
    }
}, []);  // <---------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

the reason for this is because your useEffect is being run every render. You need to add a dependency array. If you use a blank dependency array, it will only run on the first render.

This might help you understand it better.
`[https://medium.com/better-programming/understanding-the-useeffect-dependency-array-2913da504c44][1]`

```
navigator.geolocation ? let posObj = {positionAllowed: false} : let posObj = {positionAllowed: true};

const [settings, setSettings] = useState(posObj);
useEffect(() => {
    if(settings.positionAllowed&&navigator.geolocation){
        let geolocation = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((rawPosition)=>{
            let positionData = {
                positionAvailable: true,
                    data: rawPosition
                }
                if(positionData!=position){
                    setPosition(positionData);
                }
            },(err)=>{
                console.log(err);
            },{
                enableHighAccuracy: true,
                maximumAge: 10000
            });
        }
    }
}, []);
```